# Application defined or object defined error when trying to set a range = column in existing range

Tags: vba, excel

Receiving application defined or object defined error when executing "Set c = baselineChangesRange.Range("D").Find("False", LookIn:=xlValues)" in the code below.

I am trying to delete all rows where the value of the cell in the new range = "False" after referring to several of the posts here on how to do this. Obviously I am still having some trouble...

```
`
Private Sub CopyRangeToNewSheets()
compareSheet.Range("A:E").Copy
baselineChangesSheet.Range("A:E").PasteSpecial
Set baselineChangesRange = baselineChangesSheet.Range("A:E")
customChangesSheet.Range("A:E").PasteSpecial
Set customChangesRange = customChangesSheet.Range("A:E")
End Sub

Private Sub DeleteRowsWithNoBaselineChanges()
Dim c As Range

Do
    Set c = baselineChangesRange.Range("D").Find("False", LookIn:=xlValues)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete
Loop While Not c Is Nothing`
```

Comment: I doubt `Range("D")` is valid, try `Range("D:D")`.

Comment: Ugh. Can't believe I missed that. Thanks for the help - my eyes were going crossed at that time. If you would take the time to change this from a comment to an answer, I would be happy to mark as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"D"` is not a valid argument for `Range()`.

If you need a column, try `.Range("D:D")` or `.Columns("D")`.